# What does "soapy notes" mean?

Tags: meaning

In drama movie Bombshell (2019), Irena speaks on phone:

> Irena: No one around here believes Roger would want to harass
> Gretchen. I will send you some of her **soapy notes** to Roger. "Last
> night Sandra filled in  for Megyn. Why not me? Smiley face." Who sends
> a harasser a smiley face?

What does "soapy notes" mean?

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't "soppy"?

Comment: soapy it is. I am sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably "characteristic of a soap opera".

A soap opera is a long-running drama series, often featuring melodramatic storylines and overemotional plots. "Soapy" could mean "melodramatic" or "sentimental" (according to context)